# Setting Text in a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java

I'm using the code snippet below to create a JFormattedTextField. When entering values via the GUI text field the formatting works as expected. However, when I programmatically set the value the formatting does not occur. How can I force this to occur?

```
JFormattedTextField myTextField = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("#0.###"));
// Formatting Does Not Occur
myTextField.setText("555.55555");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the setValue() method

Try this

```
myTextField.setValue(new Float("555.55555"));
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to [OTisler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834233/setting-text-in-a-jformattedtextfield/1834363#1834363):

From the Javadoc for JFormattedTextField.setText()

> Note that text is not a bound
>   property, so no PropertyChangeEvent is
>   fired when it changes. To listen for
>   changes to the text, use
>   DocumentListener.

From the Javadoc for JFormattedTextField.setValue()

> Sets the value that will be formatted
>   by an AbstractFormatter obtained from
>   the current AbstractFormatterFactory.